# Connecting two private nodes on different machines

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

My college network is divided into different subnet. In a subnet, I am able to connect two different machines by admin.addPeer("enode Address with ipv6 ip and port"). But when i changes my subnet, Using the same procedure under different subnet, i am not able to connect the two nodes. To start the nodes I have used "geth --ipcdisable --port //port --rpcport //rpcport init //genesisfile". I have used same genesis file and different ports on two machines. Is there any other flag that I need to specify? or there is any problem with the subnet(maybe subnet is blocking something).

I have also add the flag --bootnodes //enode address with ipv4 and port. Same problem i.e. working under a subnetwork and not on other.

Comment: Can you `ping` between subnets without any issues?

Comment: @Richard Horrocks Yes, I am moving both the machines to a different subnet and there two nodes are not connecting.